# Varchar can not save for PHP: while

Tags: php, while-loop, varchar

I have two table buy_temp and buy_detail, i need transfer data from buy_temp to buy_detail with the same row name or types. For the first step i will get data from buy_temp like this :

```
$sid = $db->data("email", $user_session);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM buy_temp WHERE id_session='$sid'");

while ($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$cart[] = $r;
}
$j   = count($cart);
```

All data where id_session='$sid' will collect and then with action submit data will save to buy_detail

```
for($i=0;$i<$j;$i++){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO buy_detail(id_orders, id_product, qty, option) 
VALUES('$id_orders',{$cart[$i]['id_product']}, {$cart[$i]['qty']}, {$cart[$i]['option']})");}
```

But why i can't save for {$cart[$i]['option']}, when OPTION is varchar. ?

Comment: Your description is not enough to understand the problem

Comment: I said **tag**, not title. The tags are where tags belong.

Comment: The tags are clear ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Nothing get error, just not insert data OPTION row, from table buy_temp to buy_detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that i'm not enclosing text value in single quotes - it should be '{$cart[$i]['option']}'